# executing python in bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

Running `download-from-s3.py` with `python3` before the script name works but I would like to be able to run the file without it.

```
[nir test]$ ./test-download-from-s3.sh
../download-from-s3.py: line 2: import: command not found
../download-from-s3.py: line 3: import: command not found
[nir test]$ cat ./test-download-from-s3.sh
#!/bin/bash

. ../download-from-s3.py
```

I tried to put two different headers in `download-from-s3.py`, `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and `#!/usr/bin/python3`.
Neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is a shorter alias for `source`. `source` executes commands from a file *in the current shell session*. Just like you copy-pasted the python file into the script. Therefore, there's no point of selecting a different interpreter. It's really similar to `#include` in C/C++.

What you want is marking the file as executable (`chmod +x`), and then executing it just like it was a shell script:

```
./something.py
```

Note: don't use `source`/`.` for executing shell scripts either. This way, the executed script may accidentally redefine/override some of the variables or functions in the main program. Sourcing files is done when you explicitly want to import functions, read variables, etc.

Comment: @Nir Do not use `source` for executing shell scripts in other scripts, either. See my updated answer.